# Converting hsl to hex in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, hex, hsl

I have the following string taken from the [atom one-dark syntax](https://github.com/atom/one-dark-syntax/blob/master/styles/colors.less):

```
one_dark_syn = """
@hue-1:   hsl(187, 47%, 55%); // <-cyan
@hue-2:   hsl(207, 82%, 66%); // <-blue
@hue-3:   hsl(286, 60%, 67%); // <-purple
@hue-4:   hsl( 95, 38%, 62%); // <-green
@hue-5:   hsl(355, 65%, 65%); // <-red 1
@hue-5-2: hsl(  5, 48%, 51%); // <-red 2
@hue-6:   hsl( 29, 54%, 61%); // <-orange 1
@hue-6-2: hsl( 39, 67%, 69%); // <-orange 2
"""
```

I would like to use python to exchange the hsl values for hex. So far I've concocted a pretty nasty looking set of loops to parse out the values into a numpy array:

```
od_colors = [i.split(";")[0].split(":")[1] for i in one_dark_syn.split("\n") if "hsl" in i]
od_colors = [i.strip().replace("%","").replace("hsl","").replace(" ","") for i in od_colors]
od_colors = [i.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",") for i in od_colors]
od_colors = np.array(od_colors,dtype="int32")
```

See like I said nasty. Does anyone have a more pythonic way of parsing this? and most importantly how would you recommend I go about converting hsl to hex?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in CodeReview.

Comment: Your HEX is not actually HEX in every possible meaning. First, you confuse apples (hue, a number in the range 0-359) and saturation/value (numbers in the range 0-100). Second, your numbers are still decimal, not hexadecimal. Module `colorsys` https://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html has tools for conversion between HSL and RGB.

Comment: you have nice looking lines and you could use slicing to get numbers - ie `'@hue-1:   hsl(187, 47%, 55%); // <-cyan'[14:27]` gives `187, 47%, 55%`

Comment: @scotthunter why is this off topic?

Comment: You have working code you wish to improve; that's what Code Review is for.

Comment: @scotthunter I included a partial solution to a problem that I had not solved. How is that off-topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use regular expressions:

```
regex = r'hsl\(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)%,\s*(\d+)%\s*\);'
lines = [re.findall(regex,line) for line in one_dark_syn.split('\n')]
rgbs = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(int(line[0][0])/360,
                            int(line[0][1])/100,
                            int(line[0][2])/100) for line in lines if line]
# [(0.2915, 0.519842, 0.55), (0.1188, 0.41646, 0.66), (0.5762, 0.268, 0.67), 
#  (0.48257, 0.62, 0.3844), (0.65, 0.2275, 0.2627), (0.51, 0.2856, 0.2652), 
#  (0.61, 0.43981, 0.2806), (0.69, 0.528195, 0.2277)]
```

Finally, convert RGB triplets to a HEX string:

```
rgbhex = ["".join("%02X" % round(i*255) for i in rgb) for rgb in rgbs]
# ['1D3437', '0C2A42', '3A1B43', '303E26', '41171A', '331D1B', '3D2C1C', '453517']
```

Comment: For `rgbhex`, shouldn't `i` be multiplied by 255 instead of 100?

Comment: @tghw No, these are fractions of 1.

Comment: They are fractions of 1, but the output needs to be on the scale of 0x00 to 0xff, which is 0 to 255. For example, white is (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) in rgb and #FFFFFF in hex. But if you only multiply by 100, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) will turn into #646464, which is a mid-dark gray.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, @DYZ:

````
import re
import colorsys

json = '''
```json
{
    "variables":
    {
        "blue": "hsl(210, 50%, 60%)",
        "blue2": "hsl(180, 36%, 54%)",
        "green": "hsl(114, 31%, 68%)",
        "grey": "hsl(0, 0%, 73%)",
        "grey2": "hsl(0, 0%, 60%)",
        "grey3": "hsl(0, 0%, 20%)",
        "orange": "hsl(32, 93%, 66%)",
        "orange2": "hsl(32, 85%, 55%)",
        "orange3": "hsl(40, 94%, 68%)",
        "pink": "hsl(300, 30%, 68%)",
        "red": "hsl(357, 79%, 65%)",
        "red2": "hsl(13, 93%, 66%)",
        "red3": "hsl(16, 29%, 54%)",
        "white": "hsl(0, 0%, 97%)",
        "white2": "hsl(210, 11%, 85%)",
        "white3": "hsl(204, 10%, 90%)",
        "white4": "hsl(195, 11%, 93%)",
        "white5": "hsl(180, 9%, 98%)"
    }
}
'''

regex = r'hsl\(\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)%,\s*(\d+)%\s*\)'
lines = re.findall(regex,json)
rgbs = [colorsys.hls_to_rgb(int(line[0])/360,int(line[2])/100,int(line[1])/100) for line in lines]
hexs = ['#%02x%02x%02x'%(round(rgb[0]*255),round(rgb[1]*255),round(rgb[2]*255)) for rgb in rgbs]
print(hexs)
````

Comment: why all  result is 000000